# How to use last commit's contents while keeping all other commits' history?

Tags: git

For example, I have two branches all from `master`

```
master=>B1--hash01--hash02(add new file test.php: echo A > test.php)--hash03--hash04
master=>B2--hash11--hash12
```

then `B3` from `B2`

```
B2=>B3--hash21--hash22(add new file test.php: echo B > test.php)
          --hash23--hash24(mv test.php test2.php)--hash25
```

Now I want to make commits `hash21` ~ `hash25` into B1, which will generate conflicts when pick `hash22`, but the conflict is solved in `hash24`.

Is there anyway to merge commits `hash21` ~ `hash25`  into B1, only use the contents of `hash25`, while keeping all commits records.

Comment: Are you looking for `git cherry-pick -x --no-commit`? I think, using the `no-commit` flag, you can just try...